# How to group by categorical values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this -

```
Folder    FileName 
A            1
B            2
C            1
```

And I want to create one like this, which counts the occurence of each file in each folder  -

```
FileName A B C
   1     1 0 1
   2     0 1 0
```

Is there an intuitive way to achieve this?

Comment: It's `pd.crosstab(df.FileName, df.Folder)`

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
print pd.crosstab(df['Folder'],df['FileName']).T
```

As @coldspeed suggests,

```
print pd.crosstab(df['FileName'],df['Folder']) #more convenient way
```

Comment: To avoid the transpose, switch the arguments. Anyway, this is a pivot problem.

Comment: @coldspeed- you're right, I updated the solution, thanks a lot